# Mathematics language, how to say that a specific value of $x$ is included in the functions domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For instance, we have the function $y=-2(x+1)^2-10$.

$x=0$ is included in this functions domain.  How can I say this mathematically, instead of typing out a sentence and saying that $x=0$ exists in the functions domain?

Comment: We often denote this as $x \in \text{Dom}\ f$.

Comment: Some say $ x \in D(f)$..

Comment: And still others use $x\in\mathop{\textrm{dom}} f$.

Comment: $0 \in f^{-1}[\mathbb{R}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of $f(x)=y$ is $D(f)=\mathbb{R}$,since there are no restrictions for $x$.So, $x=0$ is included at the domain of $f(x)=y$.

You can symbolize this like that: $x \in D(f)=\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The question was about notation.

Comment: Oh,yes!!Is my answer better now?

Comment: Is it also acceptable to say something like $0 \in D(f)$?

Comment: @Jason Yes,it is also acceptable!!!

Answer (score 1):

If $y=f(x)$, you could also say that  $f(0)\in \mathbb{R}$.